# Search XML Tags for Name Attribute: Python elementTree module

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an XML doc in Python using the `ElementTree` module. I'm trying to look for `Elements` that have an xml tag of `entry` and a `name` attribute within that tag that equals a certain `ipAddress`. Below is my code so far:

```
tree = ET.parse(fi2)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter('entry'): #looks through child elements for tag=entry
    #look for elements that have an attribute(name)='string'
```

For reference, when I use the code `print child.tag, child.attrib` within the `for` loop, I get the following output:

```
entry {'name': 'ipAddress'}
```

I need assistance searching for `entry` tags with a `name attribute` of `ipAddress`

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(your_xml)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    if child.tag=='entry':
        for node in child:
            if node.attrib["name"]=='certain_ip':
                print("found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tree = ET.parse(fi2)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter('entry'): #looks through child elements for tag=entry
    #look for elements that have an attribute(name)='string'
    if ipAddress in child.get('name'):
        #condition is met. Execute some code. Do your thang
```